# Does my flat tire need to be replaced?

Tags: tire

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I know when to replace my tires?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/437/how-do-i-know-when-to-replace-my-tires)

The surface of my rear tire has become flattened as opposed to its original convex shape.
I have about 2,000 miles on it.  "It" is a 23 Vittorio Rubino Pro.

Comment: It only needs to be replaced when the rubber wears down to where cord is threatening to show through or you're getting a lot of flats.

Answer (score 0):

Probably getting close. As you experience more flats than normal or really begin to notice the ledge of that tire corner when you lean into a curve its probably time. Some people wait till the fabric is showing, but i dont like the amount of flats that i start getting.

2000 miles is a great life span for any tire, I say time for a new one.